# How to find out environment variables set after logging into a shell session

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, sh

How can I find out the environment variables set after logging into a shell session?

My two dummy solutions have been so far as follows:

```
_VariableName1="VarValue1";export _VariableName1;
_VariableName2="VarValue2";export _VariableName2;
```

...

```
set | grep '_'
```

… which almost shows the variables set after login (those different than the vars set `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`). This approach makes me constantly forget about the underscore in the vars – and the old gurus at work laugh at me when they see it ;)

The second approach is to use "human readable variables", but to run after login or `sudo`:

```
 su - username the 
 set > /tmp/vars.before
```

set the vars

```
 VariableName1="VarValue1";export VariableName1;
 VariableName2="VarValue2";export VariableName2;

set > /tmp/vars.after
```

… and then run the following command:

```
 comm -13 /tmp/vars.before /tmp/vars.after
```

or

```
 comm --nocheck-order -3 /tmp/vars.before /tmp/vars.after
```

depending on the `comm` binary etc.

So what is the cleanest or most clever way of finding out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to override `export` and `unset` with functions that keep track of your variables.

**Please notice that for this to work you *must* export variables like this: `export <variable>=<value>`.**

The two functions must be called `export` and `unset` and maintain a list of your variables in a file, which I'll name `~/.track$$` (`$$` is the PID of your current shell):

```
export ()
{
    if echo $@ | egrep -q '[^=]+=[^=]+' && builtin export "$@" && echo $- | grep -q i; then          # [1]
        touch ~/.track$$                                                                             # [2]
        cp -fa ~/{.track$$,.track$$.bak} 2> /dev/null;                                               # [3]  
        grep -v "^$(echo $@ | sed 's/\([^=]=\).\+/\1/')" < ~/.track$$.bak > ~/.track$$ 2> /dev/null; # [4]
        echo $@ >> ~/.track$$;                                                                       # [5]
    fi
}

unset ()
{
    if builtin unset $@ && echo $- | grep -q i; then                # [1]
        touch ~/.track$$                                            # [2]
        cp -fa ~/{.track$$,.track$$.bak} 2> /dev/null;              # [3]
        egrep -v "^$@=" < ~/.track$$.bak > ~/.track$$ 2> /dev/null; # [4]
    fi
}
```

Additionally you need to find out which environment variables you have set. An alias like this will make it:

```
alias iset="cat ~/.track$$ 2>/dev/null"
```

An alias like this:

```
alias ireset="rm ~/.track$$ >/dev/null 2>&1"
```

can be used to reset the list.

To keep the number of `~/.track$$` files to a minimum we can use this housekeeping command:

```
rm $(ls -d ~/.* | egrep 'track[0-9]+$|track[0-9]+\.bak$' | egrep -v $(ps -ef | grep bash | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/|$//')) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Where should we to put these functions, aliases, etc?

I'd would recommend that you add the functions, aliases and the housekeeping command to the end of `~/.bashrc`, so that subshells get the functions too. Depending on your distro and how `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc` and friends are executed you may define them too early (in some distros `~/.profile` sources `~/.bashrc` or the other way round) so you may have to fine tune it.

Then log out and log in again.

Now, if you run `export <variable>=<value>` in your bash session the function `export`:

- [1] checks whether the parameter is well formed (this is to avoid spurious entries when typing `export MYVAR`, because its return value is 0 and would create an entry in `~/.track$$`)
- [1] then it executes `builtin export <variable>=<value>` (this sets the variable, regardless of what happens afterwards)
- [1] then it greps `$-` to see whether this is an interactive shell (see this answer [When I ssh into a ubuntu machine, what kind of shell am I using](https://superuser.com/questions/479568/when-i-ssh-into-a-ubuntu-machine-what-kind-of-shell-am-i-using/479877#479877) [shameless plug]). By default, subshells don't inherit functions, so scripts won't create `~/.track$$` files. If a script uses `#!/bin/bash -i`, though, it will. This will prevent it.
- [2] then it touches `~/.track$$` to make sure it exists and
- [3] makes a backup copy
- [4] then it checks whether the variable already exists, if that's the case it is deleted from `~/.track$$`
- [5] finally, it adds a line to `~/.track$$`

Similarly, if you type `unset <variable>` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> the function `unset`:

- [1] executes `builtin unset <variable>` (this unsets the variable, regardless of what happens afterwards)
- [1] if `unset` was successful it checks, as in the `export` function above.  whether this is an interactive shell (see this answer [When I ssh into a ubuntu machine, what kind of shell am I using](https://superuser.com/questions/479568/when-i-ssh-into-a-ubuntu-machine-what-kind-of-shell-am-i-using/479877#479877) [shameless plug]). By default, subshells don't inherit functions, so scripts won't create `~/.track$$` files. If a script uses `#!/bin/bash -i`, though, it will. This will prevent it.
- [2] then it touches `~/.track$$` to make sure it exists and
- [3] then makes a backup copy of `~/.track$$`
- [4] removes the variable entry from `~/.track$$`

What is the `builtin` keyword I used in both functions? Since `export` or `unset` are shell builtins (that is, commands that come with the shell) I need to use `builtin`, which is itself a builtin command (from `man bash`):

> builtin shell-builtin [arguments]
>
> Execute the specified shell builtin, passing it arguments, and return its exit status.  This is useful when defining a function whose name is the same as a shell builtin, retaining the functionality of the builtin within the function. The cd builtin is commonly redefined this way. The return status is false if shell-builtin is not a shell builtin command.

The housekeeping command lists and filters the active `~/.track$$` files out and deletes the rest.

**What you get with this setup:**

- No need to use underscores anymore. Simply use the familiar `export` command (which has been overriden with a function) and it will work.
- Each `bash` session has its own `~/.track$$` file. No collisions among shells.
- As side effect from the above, subshells don't inherit the parent's `~/.track$$` file, although they inherit all environment variables.
- Environment variables set in sourced files (`. file` or `source file`) are added to `~/.track$$`.
- Environment variables set in a () subshell are also (incorrectly) tracked, because `$$` expands to the process ID of the current shell, not the subshell (see `man bash`).
- Variables are listed from first to last exported.
- Variables set by `.profile` and other scripts that you **reassign** (even with the same value) will be listed by `iset`. For instance, `HOME` is usually set by `.profile`. If you do `export HOME=/usr/local/bin:$HOME` and run `iset` you will see `HOME` listed.

**And now some examples:**

- Exported variables are shown with `iset`:

  ```
  $ export MYVAR1=0987654321; iset
  MYVAR1=0987654321
  ```
- Redefined variables are dealt with properly:

  ```
  $ export MYVAR2="this is a string"; iset
  MYVAR1=0987654321
  MYVAR2=this is a string
  $ export MYVAR2="this is a different string for the same variable"; iset
  MYVAR1=0987654321
  MYVAR2=this is a different string for the same variable
  ```
- Environment according to `env` matches `iset` output:

  ```
  $ env|grep MYVAR
  MYVAR2=this is a different string for the same variable
  MYVAR1=0987654321
  ```
- Readonly variables are not added to `~/.track$$`:

  ```
  $ export EUID=0; iset
  -bash: EUID: readonly variable
  MYVAR1=0987654321
  ```
- Old, no longer used track files are deleted when `~/.bashrc` is executed (for instance, when creating a subshell):

  ```
  $ ls -1 ~/.track*
  .track11002
  .track11002.bak
  .track21774
  .track21774.bak
  .track2923
  .track2923.bak
  .track7382
  .track7382.bak
  .track8374
  .track8374.bak
  $ echo $$
  2923
  $ bash
  <subshell>$ ls -1 ~/.track*
  .track2923
  .track2923.bak
  ```

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Your approach can be defeated in 3 ways: 1. Unset a var which was exported by .profile. (the change won't be shown) 2. Unset and re-export (to original value) a var which was exported by .profile. (it will be incorrectly listed by `iset`) 3. `export myvar; myvar=value` (`iset` will show the wrong value).

Comment: @Hugh Allen: I agree with 3., `export var=value` must be used, I edited my answer to make it clearer, thanks for perusing it and pointing that out. As of 2., if I understand correctly, the OP wishes to find out environment vars that are set (ie, that are assigned a value) after logging in, so **any** var set afterwards must be tracked. Consequently, vars exported by `.profile`, if set later, are added to `iset`. Regarding 1., I don't see how a var can be deleted from `iset`'s output if it was never added to it. 1. is desired behavior: vars set by `.profile` and not reassigned aren't monitored.

Comment: You might be right. I had assumed Yordan wanted to know about any changes including variables which were unset, as per his second approach using a comparison command.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in *environment* variables only, you should use `env` instead of `set`. I'm not quite sure whether I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, but it seems that

```
env | sort > /tmp/vars.before
```

after logging in, followed by

```
env | sort > /tmp/vars.after
comm -13 /tmp/vars.before /tmp/vars.after
```

at some later point does the right thing, at least if none of your environment variables contains a string that includes a newline. (If it does, I'd either use `env -0 | sort -z` to get the environment variables separated by NULLs and then use perl for comparison, or program the entire thing in perl.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what environment variables have been set, simply enter the following command:

```
printenv
```